# spring boot datasource tomcat jdbc properties not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, datasource

I have a Spring Boot application (version 1.5.1.RELEASE) and I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as a dependency to manage my database. I am using postgres as my database and configured it using the below properties.

```
spring.datasource.url=${POSTGRES_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${POSTGRES_USER}
```

Now when I run my tests which are almost 120, I get too many client already open error for abou 10 test cases while starting the test case itself and it fails.(remaining 100 test cases pass with success as they are able to get a connection to database)

First thing I did is increased my default postgres max connections count from 100 to 200 in the postgres server config file and my tests pass successfully after this change.

Now I investigated a bit and tried setting the parameters for connection pooling properties such as :

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=200
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=10000
```

However these properties do not work and the tests fails again giving the same error as above. I tried reading from multiple different blogs and spring documentation for setting the connection pool properties but did not find what might be going wrong with me.

I also think that if I set the above property `spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active` to 100 connections it should work with the help of tomcat jdbc pooling as i think in current scenario it is trying to open a new connection to database for each test case and I am in a fear that this same scenario might happen when I deploy this code to production environment and a new connection will be opened to the database for each request.

Does anyone have faced this problem before or is there something wrong I am doing.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: whats is the max connections configured in your database? Are there any other applications using your db? Better to check from the DB perspective/ Monitor in db the number of connections, connections leaks in your application Before jumping on conclusion of incorrect application.properties.

Comment: make sure you are closing sessions correctly

Comment: @vivek are you using hibernate orm

Comment: @KarthikPrasad 100 is the max number of connections configured in the database postgresql.conf. When I increase them to 200 it works fine. Also there are no other applications using this database. I think that if the connection pooling properties work 100 connections would suffice.

Comment: it's hard to help you without knowing what those 120 tests are doing. Spring Boot doesn't do anything special and you can configure the datasource manually if you want. But I bet it won't make any difference.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll The comment was too long because of which I have updated it here [https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8890]

Comment: There's no reason to do that. Edit your issue with more details. Again, if you want us to help you you have to detail what your tests are doing. My guess is that you're searching in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

Try upgrading Spring boot version, `1.5.10-RELEASE` is the current version.

Also, I found the connection pool properties for my application were not being applied when the property prefix `tomcat` was included. If you are still having issues try removing that.

i.e.

`spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=200`

Becomes

`spring.datasource.max-active=200`

See https://artofcode.wordpress.com/2017/10/19/spring-boot-configuration-for-tomcats-pooling-data-source