# Not all Spring JPA and datasource properties working in console application

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

Trying to configure JPA datasource in my java console app, which uses spring-data-jpa and mysql, and it seems not all defined properties are worked:

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://xyz:3306/xyz
spring.datasource.username=xyz
spring.datasource.password=xyz

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver


# Below properties don't change transactions behaviour
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop

spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout=30
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=5000
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=1
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=1
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=1
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=5000
spring.datasource.tomcat.log-abandoned=true
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

ext {
    mysqlVersion = '6.0.6'
    dbcp2Version = '2.2.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-dbcp2', dbcp2Version
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: mysqlVersion
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa") {
        exclude module: "tomcat-jdbc"
    }
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

I cannot set query timeout, cannot define reconnect to db every 5 sec (in case of abandoned connection), etc. How can I do it in java console app?

Comment: A similar question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43351733/7421645

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are including `commons-dbcp2` and cnfiguring `datasource-tomcat`.

You might want to confirm that you are using the tomcat connection pool.

If this is still a problem try removing `.tomcat` from your application properties. I was finding the same and then found this article: 
https://artofcode.wordpress.com/2017/10/19/spring-boot-configuration-for-tomcats-pooling-data-source